# How to read rtp stream in a particular port using jnetpcap

Tags: java, sockets, rtp, jnetpcap

I am trying to capture all rtp packets received in a particular port. I already know through which excat port I am receiving the packets (for generating rtp packets I am using vlc stream option). I want to use jnetpcap for easy processing. Or is there any other way to read rtp packets in java and save the payload into a sample media file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Do you have a code which you feel is not working or Wrong?

Comment: I have tried opening datagramsocket and receive the packets. I am able to receive packets through datagramsocket, but I am not able to extract payload for the packet. So was looking for any method that would help.

Comment: Share your effort here, like the code you wrote. Probably people can help you in fixing it. Else the question may be closed, as it does not comply to standards. Check How To Ask section for more information ?